# Exiting visual-regexp search with a cursor motion command doesn't execute that command

Tags: search

I recently set up the `visual-regexp-steroids` package to try it out.  The one major sticking point so far has been that when I terminate the search by typing a cursor motion command (typically `M-<` or `C-a`), the cursor is just left where it is; I have to type the command a second time to make it work.

Looking at the source for both `visual-regexp` and `visual-regexp-steroids`, I don't find any configurable option for this behavior.  I also don't find any relevant issues filed against either package's Github page.

Is there any way to get the usual Emacs exit-search behavior when using `visual-regexp` or `visual-regexp-steroids`?

--

Here's what I tried just now:

I deleted `~/.emacs`, started Emacs, and opened a file.  I evaluated `(require 'package)` and `(require 'visual-regexp-steroids)`, then typed <kbd>M-x</kbd>`vr/isearch-forward` and typed some keys that matched some text present in the file.  Then when I pressed <kbd>M-<</kbd>, the search stopped, but the cursor was left at the end of the matching text.

Comment: Works fine for me. Have you tried with `emacs -q`?

Comment: @nega I tried that and just added more details to the questions describing what happened.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your original question. The behavior I'm getting is exactly as you describe. I'd send this as a [feature request](https://github.com/benma/visual-regexp-steroids.el/issues) to the authors.